# Linear combinations of indicator functions of measurable rectangles with sides of finite measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, limits

The following is a question on measure theory whose answer would help me greatly in my research.

> Let $ (X,\mathcal{F},\mu) $ and $ (Y,\mathcal{G},\nu) $ be $ \sigma $-finite measure spaces. Let $ E $ be a $ (\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{G}) $-measurable subset of $ X \times Y $ such that $ (\mu \otimes \nu)(E) < \infty $.
>
> Is it true that the indicator function $ \mathbf{1}_{E} $ is the pointwise limit of a sequence $ (s_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ of functions on $ X \times Y $, where for each $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, we require that $ s_{n} $ be a finite linear combination of functions of the form $ \mathbf{1}_{A \times B} $, where $ A \in \mathcal{F} $, $ B \in \mathcal{G} $ and $ \mu(A),\nu(B) < \infty $? In other words, for each $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, we require that $ s_{n} $ be a finite linear combination of indicator functions of measurable rectangles whose sides have finite measure.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is true.

---

**Notation**

Let $ \mathcal{R} $ denote the collection of measurable rectangles in $ X \times Y $ with sides of finite measure.

**Note:** The null set $ \varnothing = \varnothing \times \varnothing $ is considered to be a measurable rectangle.

Let $ \mathcal{R}_{\sigma} $ denote the collection of subsets of $ X \times Y $ that are a countable union of elements of $ \mathcal{R} $.

---

**Step 1**

Fix $ \epsilon > 0 $, and let $ E $ be an $ (\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{G}) $-measurable subset of $ X \times Y $ with finite measure. Then there exists an $ A \in \mathcal{R}_{\sigma} $ such that
$$
E \subseteq A
\quad \text{and} \quad
(\mu \otimes \nu)(A \setminus E) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$
This is part of the construction of the Carathéodory measure from a pre-measure (or any general set function). The Lebesgue measure on $ \mathbb{R} $ is constructed in this manner.

As $ A \in \mathcal{R}_{\sigma} $, we can find a sequence $ (R_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ in $ \mathcal{R} $ such that $ \displaystyle A = \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} R_{n} $. Then
$$
E \subseteq \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} R_{n}
\quad \text{and} \quad
  (\mu \otimes \nu) \! \left( \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} R_{n} ~ \Bigg\backslash ~ E \right)
< \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$

**Note:** We did not use the outer measure $ (\mu \otimes \nu)^{*} $ as we have assumed that $ E $ is measurable.

---

**Step 2**

Each $ A \in \mathcal{R}_{\sigma} $ is a countable union of *disjoint* measurable rectangles. Therefore, by Step 1, there is a sequence $ (D_{i})_{i \in \mathbb{N}} $ of *disjoint* measurable rectangles such that $ \displaystyle E \subseteq \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} D_{i} $ and
$$
  (\mu \otimes \nu) \! \left( \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} D_{i} ~ \Bigg\backslash ~ E \right)
< \frac{\epsilon}{2},
\quad \text{or equivalently}, \quad
  \left\| \chi_{\bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} D_{i}} - \chi_{E} \right\|_{L^{1}}
< \frac{\epsilon}{2}. \quad \quad (1)
$$

---

**Step 3**

Now, there exists an $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that
$$
  (\mu \otimes \nu) \!
  \left(
  \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} D_{i} ~ \Bigg\backslash ~ \bigcup_{i = 1}^{N} D_{i}
  \right)
< \frac{\epsilon}{2},
\quad \text{or equivalently}, \quad
  \left\|
  \chi_{\bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} D_{i}} - \chi_{\bigcup_{i = 1}^{N} D_{i}}
  \right\|_{L^{1}}
< \frac{\epsilon}{2}. \quad (2)
$$
Combining $ (1) $ and $ (2) $, we have
$$
  \left\| \chi_{E} - \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \chi_{D_{i}} \right\|_{L^{1}}
= \left\| \chi_{E} - \chi_{\bigcup_{i = 1}^{N} D_{i}} \right\|_{L^{1}}
< \epsilon.
$$
As $ \epsilon $ is arbitrary, we can approximate $ \chi_{E} $ in the $ L^{1} $-sense by a sequence $ (s_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $, where each $ s_{n} $ is a finite sum of indicator functions of disjoint measurable rectangles whose sides have finite measure.

As there is a subsequence $ (s_{n_{k}})_{k \in \mathbb{N}} $ such that $ \displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} s_{n_{k}} = \chi_{E} $ pointwise almost-everywhere, we are done.

**Note:** Every $ L^{1} $-convergent sequence of functions contains a subsequence that converges to the very same limit pointwise almost-everywhere.

Comment: Dear Xiao, thank you for your answer. It’ll take me a while to study your solution. I do have one question however. Is it possible to obtain pointwise convergence *everywhere* rather than pointwise convergence *almost everywhere*?

Comment: I am not sure at the moment, and I will look into it.

Comment: @BerrickFillmore I made a mistake in my step 2, please wait for my update :(

Comment: Okay, I fixed the mistake.

Comment: Hi Xiao. I edited your answer so that I could understand it better. I hope you don’t mind. =) I modified the definition of $ \mathcal{R} $ to be the collection of all measurable rectangles with sides of *finite* measure. Although the construction of the Carathéodory measure requires us to consider arbitrary measurable rectangles, which may have a side of infinite measure, we can do away with this requirement and consider only measurable rectangles whose sides have finite measure without affecting the resulting measure. This is possible precisely because of the $ \sigma $-finiteness condition.

Comment: Hi Berrick, that looks great! And a counter example for pointwise everywhere convergence. Let us work in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and take $E$ to be $$\{0\}\times \{\text{ a non-Lebesgue measurable set in }\mathbb{R}\}.$$ $E$ is Lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb{R}^2$ since it has measure $0$. However, any approximation we make with unions of rectangles, we will never get the exact set $\pi_Y(E)$ the non Lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb{R}$. Thus the characteristic functions can not converge pointwise everywhere.